# Flutter -- Problem with Image FrameBuilder

Tags: flutter

I'm using framebuilder within Listview.builder to fade in a list of images.  It is a very nice effect.  One problem I am having though:  when I Navigator.pop back to this image list screen, the images keep fading in.  In this case, considering they are already loaded, shouldn't this not happen?  Thank you in advance.

```dart
Image.file(
  File(Words.fromJson(jsonDecode(wordData[index])).imagePath),
  gaplessPlayback: true,
  frameBuilder: (context, child, frame, wasSynchronouslyLoaded) {
    if (wasSynchronouslyLoaded) {
      return child;
    } else {
      return AnimatedOpacity(
        child: child,
        opacity: frame == null ? 0 : 1,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
        curve: Curves.easeOut,
      );
    }
  },
  cacheWidth: 200,
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping the class where your Image is being loading with this? :

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Container(
      // Image Code
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked!  Specifically the adding of "super.build(context);" did the trick.  I also added "addAutomaticKeepAlives: true" to the Listview.builder.  Thank you for your help.